# Git error since working with 1.x prefixed branches

Tags: git, gitlab

Lately we have release version 2 of our product. But we are still supporting our previous version. To keep some structure in our GIT branches we started prefixing the v1 features with 1.x/...
Ever since we frequently get errors like these:

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/1.x/feature/xxx': unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/1.x/feature/xxx: Not a directory
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `1.x/feature` branch (with no `/xxx` afterwards) on `origin` ?

Comment: What says `git branch -a`?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes we do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the presence if a branch named `1.x/feature` on your remote server.

If this remote branch is not used anymore, try deleting it ; otherwise, try to rename it.

---

Branches are matched to actual files in your `.git/` folder. Try the following command from your git directory in a terminal :

```
# short story is : remote branches are stored in .git/refs/remotes/origin/
$ ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/1.x/
```

You should see a *file* `aaa` for a branch named `1.x/aaa` and a *directory* `bbb` for branches named `1.x/bbb/xxx`.

With two branches named `1.x/feature` and `1.x/feature/xxx`, git will try to create both a file and a directory named `feature`, and one of the two actions will fail.